# Video constraints facingmode not switching 2nd time

Tags: javascript, angular, getusermedia

I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) to switch between front-camera and back-camera. 1st time it's working perfectly.

1st-time `facingMode:  "user"` to `facingMode: "environment"` => Working,
`faceingMode: "environment"` to `faceingMode: "user"` => Working,
2nd-time facingMode: "user" to facingMode: "environment" => not working,
`facingMode: "environment"` to `facingMode: "user"` => working,
3rd-time `facingMode: "user"` to `facingMode: "environment"` => not working,
`facingMode: "environment"` to `facingMode: "user"` => working.

I don't know why it's behaving like that. I tested it in multiple devices Sony Xperia and Realme, redmi, oppo, Vivo, Samsung in chrome browser. Sony Xperia and Samsung working perfectly without any issue. but remaining devices having the above issue.
how to solve this issue?

```
changeFacingMode() {
    if (this.localStream) {
        this.localVideo.pause();
        this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        track.stop();
        });
        this.localVideo.srcObject = null;
    }
    if (this.isFacingMode) {
        this.constraints = { audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } };
        this.isFacingMode = false;
    } else {
        this.constraints = { audio: true, video: { facingMode: "user" } };
        this.isFacingMode = true;
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints).then((stream) => {
        this.localStream = stream;
        this.localVideo.srcObject = this.localStream;
        this.localVideo.play();
    }).catch(err => this.handleError(err));
      
}
```

Comment: Did u fix this issue